# HLS streaming subtitle not working in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am trying to implement subtitles in video in iOS and I am using two URLS to test

let **videoURL1** = "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8"

let **videoURL2** = "https://cdnapi.bamboo-video.com/api/entry/0_eyd4078h/flavors/playlist.m3u8?iid=61cc500b063044343757586c"

Code for displaying subtitle:

```
let asset = playerItem!.asset
                
asset.loadMediaSelectionGroup(for: .legible) { grp, error in
    if grp!.options.count > 0 {
        self.playerItem?.select(grp!.options[0], in: grp!)
        print(grp!.options[0])
    }
}
```

I can see subtitle for **videoURL1** but for **videoURL2** subtitle is not working.

The print log for **videoURL1** is:

```
<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x600002e2fe40, language = de, mediaType = 'sbtl', title = Deutsch>
```

The print log for **videoURL2** is:

```
<AVMediaSelectionKeyValueOption: 0x600001adff40, language = en, mediaType = 'sbtl', title = English, auxiliary = YES>
```

I don't know if it has to do something with property **auxiliary = YES** for **videoURL2**

**m3u8 files for**

**videoURL1**: https://pastebin.com/sc5TZPm8

**videoURL2** https://pastebin.com/5reZYQhC

**HLS Validation Report**

**videoURL1**: https://prajeet.tiiny.site/test_report.html

**videoURL2** https://prajeet.tiiny.site/bamboo_report.html

Answer (score 1):

There is not problem in iOS app implementation where you use `asset.loadMediaSelectionGroup` but rather subtitles provided with the .m3u8 playlist. It seems that these are badly regenerated subtitles from `.srt` (iOS cannot use .srt files therefore the regeneration) to `.vtt` file option. Please contact the VOD provider and claim that subtitles are not correct according to WebVTT specification. `Streamvalidator` that you propably used for validating stream also suggests the issue on this line:

> 18. (Segment) You SHOULD use the recommended MIME types.

```
All Renditions, Received: text/vtt, Expected text/plain
```

Comment: Also for videoURL2 playlist https://pastebin.com/5reZYQhC, it is a multivariant playlist, for which SUBTITLES property is missing in #EXT-X-STREAM-INF: TAGS, but it's present in videoURL1 playlist https://pastebin.com/sc5TZPm8